# whats the difference between B = Button(....).grid() and B = Button(...) B.grid() in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter and i was experimenting on buttons, and i noticed that sometimes same kind of code works and sometimes not.

for example whats the difference between:

```
button1 = Button(root, text="test").grid(column=1, row=1)
```

and

```
button1 = Button(root, text="test")
button1.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

Comment: The first version sets `button1` to the return value of `.grid()`, which is None.  In other words, there's no point in assigning the variable at all, it certainly is not a "button".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
button1 = Button(root, text="test").grid(column=1, row=1)
```

Sets button1 to the return value of .grid(), which is nothing. This doesnt create a button variable/reference at all. This means you will not be able to configure the button later on using button1.config() because the button1 reference doesnt exist.

This:

```
button1 = Button(root, text="test")
button1.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

Creates the button1 variable/reference. This creates the button in a way where you will be able to configure the button later on using button1.config(). E.g. to change its text.

Comment: ah i see.. so it is necessary when you want to make changes with button during running program right? for example to change the size or place of button by just clicking it

Comment: Yes. If you create the button using the first method then the 'button1' variable name / reference is not actually created. This means you have no way of referencing the button and therefore you have no reference to use for re-configuring and changing the button later on. For example, you wont be able to do button1.config(text='NewButton1Text') because the program wont understand the button1 reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the second one

```
button1 = Button(root, text="test") #here you are creating an Tkinter label object
#Now you can configure the label object by simply using the button1 variable

button1.grid(column=1, row=1) #positing it in the frame using grid-method
```

In the first one

```
button1 = Button(root, text="test").grid(column=1, row=1)
```

By using this method if you later want to change something in it like its name or something you will find it difficult to change.

Actually using this

```
button1 = Button(root, text="test").grid(column=1, row=1)
```

is like using this

```
Button(root, text="test").grid(column=1, row=1)
```